# FN key on Apple Magic Keyboard via USB not working

Tags: keyboard, usb

I've installed elementary OS 0.4 Loki (64-bit) on my desktop PC and I'm using an Apple Magic Keyboard via USB and/or Bluetooth.
Everything works fine but I can't use the `fn` key to get to input things like forward delete and so on...

The keyboard works with no problems via Bluetooth or USB on my MacBook air.

I've been searching on google and this stackexchange page but I can only find people complaining about pairing via Bluetooth and all the links point to this doc page: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AppleKeyboard
None of the solutions there seem to work.

---

As mike-wild suggested, I tried using `xev` 
No matter if I press Backspace or `fn` + `Backspace` the output is the same:

`KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001, root 0xf4,     subw 0x0, time 138447, (270,71), root:(1194,356), state 0x0, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES, XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) " XFilterEvent returns: False –`

I'm now wondering, do I need any specific driver? How come Macbooks + elementary have the `fn` key working but mine doesn't?

Comment: First of all, which keyboard layout are you using (`Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Layout`)? You will probably want to set this to something like *English (Macintosh)*. Open up a terminal and type `xev`, this will bring up a window where you can test keyboard input and see the corresponding keycodes printed in the terminal. Press `Backspace` and `fn` + `Backspace` then compare the output. Post it here if possible.

Comment: Hello there! I did selected the English (Macintosh) layout. Tried xev but no matter if I press `Backspace` or `fn` + `Backspace` the output is the same:
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2c00001,
    root 0xf4, subw 0x0, time 138447, (270,71), root:(1194,356),
    state 0x0, keycode 22 (keysym 0xff08, BackSpace), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (08) "
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Comment: Don't forget to update your question with that output :) On mine I get the output [here](http://pastebin.com/1GLpPdNE) - notice that it doesn't explicitly mention the `fn` key being pressed, however the keycode changes to 'Delete'. I thought that the `fn` keypress doesn't actually make it to the OS, rather it's the keyboard sending `Delete` instead of `Backspace`. Have you verified that the `fn` key works when connected to another machine?

Comment: Hello Mike, I added the edit on the question! Yes the keyboard is working on my Macbook with no problems :/ I'm wondering that maybe there is an issue with missing drivers?